# Adding dates to Microsoft Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am adding recurring events to my Outlook Calendar using a .csv file.  What is the earliest date (year) that can be added i.e. my birth year 1970.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the earliest date (year) that can be added

> - The first day you can select in Outlook’s calendar is April 1, 1601
> - The last day you can select in Outlook’s calendar is August 31, 4500
>
> Why are these dates chosen? I don’t know. I do know that the entire
>   system of Windows uses the date 01/01/1601 as a base for file dates
>   and Active Directory uses it for logon dates, so perhaps the Outlook
>   team had some fun with that (although putting Easter eggs in
>   applications is no longer allowed at Microsoft)? And perhaps August
>   31, 4500 is Microsoft’s end-of-the-world prediction?

Source [Calendar trivia](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/208)